# hide uiimagepickercontroller interface?

Tags: ios, xcode

when using uiimagepicker, I was wondering if there was a way to hide the viewcontroller / preview of what is being taken i.e. the same way you would skip the part where the video preview layer is set in an AVFoundation instance.

Comment: I am not sure with your requirement. Do you want image selection without preview? If you can check ALAssets library once? It may help.

Comment: yes i want to take a picture using takePicture. I want to hide the sutter sound, and not show the actual uiimage picker. Ie if viewcontroller 1 was just a black screen that said 'hi' with a button to segue to viewcontroller2; i want to use the takePicture function onload when the user sees viewcontroller2. I got this to work, now i just need to hide the view of whats being taken and turn off the shutter sound.